# WPF and MVVM: pass object using binding through nested UserControl and ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have the object `MyObject Object` in the class `MainClass.xaml`.
I want to pass this object to a `ViewModel` class of a nested user control called `SubSubUserControl` through a `SubUserControl`.

Here is the code in `MainClass.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.SubUserControl"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=local:SubUserControlViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <local:SubSubUserControl Object="{Binding Object, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SubUserControl}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In `SubUserControl` I have a classical `DependencyProperty` in order to pass `Object` to it.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Object), typeof(Object), typeof(SubUserControl));

public Object Object
{
    get => (Object)GetValue(ObjectProperty);
    set => SetValue(ObjectProperty, value);
}

protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new SubUserControlViewModel(Object);
    base.OnInitialized(e);
}
```

`SubUserControl` is only a "bridge", the object `Object` is needed in `SubSubUserControl`.
I pass to it with a binding (changing Datacontex beacause the standard DataContext for `SubUserControl` is his ViewModel).

```
<local:SubSubUserControl Object="{Binding Object, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

and `SubSubUserControl` has the classical `DependencyProperty`.

`SubSubUserControl` has a ViewModel as DataContext and I'd like to pass that object to it.
I try with

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Object), typeof(Object), typeof(SubSubUserControl));

public Object Object
{
    get => (Object)GetValue(ObjectProperty);
    set => SetValue(ObjectProperty, value);
}

protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new SubSubUserControlViewModel(Object);
    base.OnInitialized(e);
}
```

but `Object` is `null`.
The same code in `SubUserControl` works.

Is there a way to pass an object using binding to a ViewModel class that belongs to a nested UserControl?

I saw a lot of similar questions but noone works with my specific case...

**EDIT**

The class `Object` is instanced code-behind in `MainClass.xaml.cs`. In order to pass it I set the DataContext of `MainClass` to `Self`.

```
public MyObject Object { get; set; } = new MyObject();
```

Here is how I set DataContext in `MainClass.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <local:SubUserControl Object="{Binding Object}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Setting the DataContext to the entire `Window` avoid me to write something like `ElementName` or `Relative Source`.

P.s. Resharper do not warn me about any DataContext, each instance is seen correctly.

Comment: In general, controls never set their own DataContext. They usually inherit the DataContext from their parent element.

Comment: @Clemens I'd like to have two different DataContext for the two different ViewModel... Otherwise I have to put everyting in one ViewModel, isn't it?

Comment: No, typically the DataContext is set where the UserControl is used. This may for example be done by the Content of a ContentControl that has the UserControl in its ContentTemplate. You can set whatever object you like, e.g. the value of a property of a main view model. Different "sub view models" may be provided by different properties of a main view model.

Comment: We do not see the initial setting of Object in the MainClass.xaml . The first bind path is just "Object" , this goes to the DataContext which we do not see. If "Object" is defined in Code Behind and is part of the MainClass control , we should expect ElementName or Relative Source .  Please clear it up.

Comment: Can you show how is initialized the `MainClass`'s data context?

Comment: @vernou I edited my question. The DataContext is set to the entire Window using `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Comment: @GiladWaisel I edited my question. The DataContext is set to the entire Window using `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` and the object is set code behind in a property (`public MyObject Object { get; set; } = new MyObject();`). I could not understand why in the first UserControl (`SubUserControl`) I can see the object correctly while in the second is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the method `OnInitialized`, but from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.oninitialized) :

> Raises the Initialized event.

And the event [Initialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized) :

> Whether you choose to handle Loaded or Initialized depends on your requirements. If you do not need to read element properties, intend to reset properties, and do not need any layout information, Initialized might be the better event to act upon. If you need all properties of the element to be available, and you will be setting properties that are likely to reset the layout, Loaded might be the better event to act upon.

I think the binding work, but you try to read the value in `OnInitialized` that is called before the binding is resolved.

As suggested in the documentation, maybe you can use the event Loaded like :

```cs
public partial class SubSubUserControl : UserControl
{
    public SubSubUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += SubSubControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void SubSubControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new SubSubViewModel(TargetFoo);
    }
}
```

---

A alternative is to update the data context when the dependency property is modified :

```cs
public partial class SubSubUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Object", typeof(MyObject),
        typeof(SubSubUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnObjectChanged)
    );

    private static void OnObjectChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is SubSubControl ssc)
        {
            ssc.DataContext = new SubSubViewModel((MyObject)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT from exchanges in comments.

It looks like you have a binding problem too. I suspect that a other element of type UserControl encapsulate the SubSubUserControl, like :

```
MainClass
  SubUserControl
     OtherUserControl
         SubSubUserControl
```

In this case, the binding will use OtherUserControl as source (and not the expected `SubUserControl`).

In this case, you can specify in the binding the source's type is `SubUserControl` to avoid a other element of type UserControl is selected :

```xml
<local:SubSubUserControl Object="{Binding BridgeFoo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:SubUserControl}}}" />
```

A alternative is to use `Binding.ElementName` instead of `Binding.RelativeSource` :

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectNamespace.SubUserControl"
             ...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectNamespace"
             Name="Sub">
    <local:SubSubUserControl Object="{Binding Object, ElementName=Sub}" />
</UserControl>
```

I prefer this, because I never remember the RelativeSource syntax.

Comment: The first solution does not work: `TargetFoo` is null during the Loaded callback. The second one do not work either because the `OnObjectChanged` is never called... :(

Comment: Sound the problem is the binding. Do you try to replace RelativeSource by ElementName in `SubSubUserControl.xaml`?

Comment: It works!! The problem is that I wrote "RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" instead of ElementName="UserControlName". I could not understand why but it's ok. If you edit your answer I'll check as correct.

Comment: @Rowandish, You are welcome. I edited my answer to add this information.